# Inspect angular material theming source code

Tags: angular, sass, visual-studio-code, angular-material

How can I read certain definitions of the material theming?

I'm using **Visual Studio Code** and with **SCSS IntelliSense** extension  but I'm not being able to find the definition of the @angular module itself.

I'm importing the module with `@import '~@angular/material/theming'` and everything is working great, the app is working good.

The only issue is that when I try to look for the definition of anything from the material theming (`angular-material-theme` for example) I get `"No definition found found ..."`

Any ideas on how to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

You can find the file under node_modules/@angular/material/_theming.scss.

The underscore at the beginning of the filename means, that the file is a partial, so it can be imported without using the leading underscore.

I don't know, if you are familiar with partials, but the Sass [documentation](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#partials) defines a partial as follows:

> If you have a SCSS or Sass file that you want to import but don't want to compile to a CSS file, you can add an underscore to the beginning of the filename. This will tell Sass not to compile it to a normal CSS file. You can then import these files without using the underscore.